# How do I execute a remote command upoin connection with Remote-SSH in VSCode? (NOT the terminal)

Tags: ssh, remote, visual-studio-code

The remote system is appropriately lock down except for a few folks with sudo ability.  Using VSCode with the Remote-SSH extension I can connect and examine much of the directory structure however, there is much that is visible only to root.  Opening a Terminal session I am able to run 'sudo' and see the entire file system.  What I'd like to do is be able to use VSCode features to examine, edit, etc. with the graphical (-ish) features of VSCode rather than just the Terminal.

It appears that Remote-SSH will only honor the most basic form of the ssh command and ignores all options given on the command liner or in the configuration file - most notably in this instance, the RemoteCommand and ProxyCommand options...
Does anyone know of a way (short of writing my own extension) way to cause this to work?

Answer (score 1):

## Enable `RemoteCommand` in Visual Studio Code

There is a Visual Studio Code setting to enable the `RemoteCommand` option in the SSH config file[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4474).  In your VS Code user settings under the Remote SSH section, enable the "Enable Remote Command" and "Use Local Server" options.  The JSON settings look like:

```
"remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": true,
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true,
```

## Use `RemoteCommand` in SSH config

Once these settings are enabled, the `RemoteCommand` option will be observed during SSH connection.  For example (in `.ssh/config`):

```
Host myhost
  HostName myhost.example.com
  User username
  RemoteCommand echo Hello world && /bin/bash
```